# Creating non ascii characters with php

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is anyway to create non ASCII codes (alt codes) via php. 
For example Alt + 0134 gives this character †, i want to do it with php.

Thank you

Comment: where you want to output it? in a browser? console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) function:

From the documentation page:

> Returns a one-character string containing the character specified by ascii.

It's as simple as:

```
echo chr('0134');
```

Outputs:

```
†
```

Comment: i still have a problem, when outputting those characters in a file , say a .txt or .csv , after opening the file i see ? in a square in the csv and DC4 in notepad++